# Race condition makes nHibernate to create duplicate entry

Tags: c#, multithreading, sql-server-2008, nhibernate, race-condition

I have a race condition on nHibernate that's creating duplicate entries on my database. Unfortunately, I cannot create an `UNIQUE` index on database, thus I would like to solve this error using only nHibernate methods. It is a web application that might run on a web farm (hence I guess a system lock should not solve the problem neither). The simplified situation follows:

```cs
var current = UnitOfWorkManager.Instance.Current;
current.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable);
try {

    var myEntity = MyFactory.MyEntityRepository.GetBy(product, company);
    // race condition happens between the previous statement and Save() method.

    if (myEntity == null)
    {
      myEntity = new MyEntity();
      myEntity.Product     = product;
      myEntity.Company     = company;
      myEntity.Date        = date;
      myEntity.CurrentUser = currentUser;
      myEntity.IsManual    = true;
      myEntity.Save();
    }
    else
    {
      myEntity.IsManual    = false;
      myEntity.Save();
    }
    current.CommitTransaction();
}
catch {
    current.RollbackTransaction();
    throw;
}
```

I am new to nHibernate so maybe I am missing some basics here. I'd appreciate any feedback. :)

Comment: myEntity.Save(); should be in a transaction.

Comment: It's not really clear what the nature of your race condition is.

Comment: The database concept you are looking for is a transaction. You need to create a transaction with lock for update starting at the GetBy and ending at the Save. I can'y tell you how to do that in Hibernate however.

Comment: @DarrenDavies, this code is contained into a transaction coordinated by a UnitOfWorkManager (code was updated to show). I even set the isolation level to Serializable hoping it would lock the entire table until commit, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @BrianO''Byrne please check my previous comment -- cannot refer to more than one user in each comment ...

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, the race condition happens when two users test if the myEntity instance exists to decide whether to create a new instance or update the existing one; if both users test the existing condition at the "same time", both will create new instances and, since I cannot alter the database to create the UNIQUE constraint, both will succeed.

Comment: @GerardoLima: The database is the only instance that could provide the necessary synchronization. NHibernate can't help you here, especially when we are talking about a distributed system. In that case you have multiple processes that execute your code. If you don't have multiple processes, a simple solution would be to always allow only one thread access to that piece of code via `lock`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, I am sorry to ask, but are you 100% sure nHibernate can't help here? I'm new to this framework and I'd rather like to believe it's just my ignorance than such a well known framework should have ways to solve this common problem...

Comment: @GerardoLima: NHibernate is a part of your applications process. How is it supposed to help you if you can't adjust the database? NHibernate is not a cure for bad decision in the database design. That's how you solve this common problem: *Fix your database*. NHibernate basically is a library that generates SQL and interprets the results. Would you be able to achieve what you are trying to achieve with SQL alone?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, If I had access to the SQL server I could lock the table during the transaction (or even create my own lock table), it would provide me with the necessary synchronization. I'm trying to adjust my thoughts to the nHibernate way to solve this problem, though. Any suggestion left on how to do it?

Comment: @GerardoLima: What kind of access do you need to create a table lock? If that's the same kind of access that you need for a normal query you might have a chance. In that case you should ask that concrete question - after searching and not finding an answer: "How to make NHibernate issue a table lock for my transaction?".

Comment: BTW: There isn't really "the NHibernate way" to solve things. Conceptually, NHibernate is only a helper library that writes the SQL statements for you. But it's still a RDBMS underneath and it still uses SQL...

Comment: i guess you have confused myEntity.Save() with session.Save(myEntity), haven't you? Or is the entity accessing the session, and if so, how and which session?
The Save() @ else should be obsolete since NHibernate tracks changes and updates the entity automatically when committing.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit, I guess not ... from the feedback I got here I think nHibernate can't accommodate this pattern -- I don't like it, but we can't be very picky and re-implement a great deal of an application because of a maintenance task.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the nHibernate Manual, I think your problem is maybe your second call to save if subProjectToSupplier isn't null. Because the nHibernate manual says "save" does an insert.

Try SaveOrUpdate

Comment: In this particular case, I need a new row to be inserted into database or fail.

Comment: The `SaveOrUpdate` should not solve the problem, though, because it's based on ID and a new different ID would've been created for each entity instance...

Comment: If your data is dupplicated, one of your calls to save must be your problem. If it's not the second then it must be the first. Your new entity gets the same product and company you searched before.

Comment: If your code is called twice, then your call to your function must be synchronized. nHibernates Sessions aren't thread safe! You have to synchronize access to them.

Comment: That's my problem, @user743414, my application runs on a web-farm to serve clients over Internet, so I don't really have an option to make it single-threaded or synchronize threads using dotNet regular locks. I need a pattern that uses nHibernate for persistence and implement some sort of lock (or alternative) to prevent race conditions.

Comment: nHibernate doesn't have such an option.
You have to build your own.

Create a new table [mylocks(nvarchar)] and a unique index on the nvarchar field. Just make a insert to that table, when you get an exception you know you are the second who tries to insert this data.
You could make the insert in your begin transaction or add this logic to your MyEntity class. Should run fast enough.

Comment: I already had considered this (to create a table to hold application locks), @user743414. Although it should solve my problem, I still think is to ... hackish. I really expected nHibernate to work in real world Internet applications, but it seems to lack this basic building block. (please see my comment on Jul 9 at 14:10)

Comment: Another question would be, why is this code called by two or more webservers "at the same"? I don't know your application nor your design. Maybe there is some other design issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your `Save()` in a transaction, ideally you could implement a pattern such as `IUnitOfWork` or use the `SessionFactory`, for example:

```
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction()) {
  myEntity = new MyEntity();
  myEntity.Product = product;
  myEntity.Company = company;
  myEntity.Date = date;
  myEntity.CurrentUser = currentUser;
  myEntity.IsManual = true;
  myEntity.Save();
  transaction.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Darren Davies, but I'm already using a UnitOfWork implementation to create a transaction (I updated the question to show it). The point I got is that it seems there's nothing to lock because no record was fetched from repository, so both threads can create their instance ... any thoughts?

Comment: @GerardoLima - maybe have a boolean  indicating that it is creating a new type of `MyEntity` so the other transaction has to wait until it's complete.

Comment: @Daren Davies - This suggestion actually looks like creating a `lock`. Then I get the to problem: where should I put the lock on? As the system runs on a web-farm it is not feasible to create an application (or machine) wise lock and I don't know any way to tell nHibernate to put such lock on database...

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you are asking for NHibernate solution here. I am not sure if this can solve in 100% your problem but try this one.

1. Use ReadCommitted isolation level.
2. Implement an interceptor for your needs http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/#manipulatingdata-interceptors

Within the interceptor you can do:

1. Query the DB if there is a record on your unique column. Then you can apply some sort of a merge mechanism
2. Check the current session if there are other objects like yours pending to be persisted.

================

Other solution is to keep shared cache of between the farm (memcache) and track objects you do not want to be duplicated.

PS: I can talk more about each point. Just tell me if something sounds like a solution for you

Comment: Actually I'm not experienced on nHibernate -- and I don't know what an Interceptor is -- so I'd appreciate if you explained this suggestion in detail.